# Is there such a thing like mimicry?

Tags: javascript, css

so I want an element to follow particular characteristics of another element like height width and position, but I want to avoid others like filters, is there a way to do something like:

```
div{
mimic: #id(width height position);
}
```

Where div always gets the width and height values (of the current rendered page) and not percentages.

I suppose this can be done with js with a few attributes grabbing...

Comment: You're supposing right. That's the way to do it!

Comment: Answered your own question there, didn't you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the same styling properties to multiple selectors by separating them with a comma:

```css
#id, div {             /* Properties shared by both #id and div selectors. */
    height: ...;
    width: ...;
    ...
}

#id {                  /* Properties specific to the #id selector. */
    ...
}

div {                  /* Properties specific to the div selector. */
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you can give your elements a shared class name, and style on the class selector:

```html
<div class="myClass">...</div>
<elem id="id" class="myClass">...</elem>
```

```css
.myClass {             /* Properties shared by elements with class "myClass". */
    height: ...;
    width: ...;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Let me be more clear, what I want is specific to dynamic widths and heights. Take the case, there is a div with a ul in it, the div takes the dimensions of the UL in it, now I want another div to take the dimensions of the div containing the UL, but I can't do that by sharing the same properties, I don't know how big the UL is gonna be so I need the div to mimic the other div on page rendered.

Comment: @untore there are countless possible solutions to this problem, but without being able to see any of your markup nobody will be able to help you here.